# Sitecore 9.1 When a specific user is trying to login we see a blank "An Error occurred screen"

Tags: sitecore-client

Sitecore 9.1 When a specific user is trying to login we see a blank "An Error occurred" screen. It is working fine for other users. In the backend CM logs we see this error message

```
Nested Exception

    Exception: System.Data.DataException
    Message: Error executing SQL command:  INSERT INTO [Properties] (   [Key], [Value] ) VALUES (   @name, @value )

    Nested Exception

    Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
    Message: String or binary data would be truncated.
    The statement has been terminated.
    Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
```

Comment: Is there anythings special about the username? Extra long maybe?

Comment: In SQL server DB this issue come when you are entering data ex- username is more length compare to mention in table.

Comment: Related issue https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25217/sitecore-identity-server-on-prem-throws-error-an-error-occured

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- delete the existing tickets (note that this step will logout the users):
  DELETE
  FROM [YourCoreDatabase].[dbo].[Properties]
  WHERE [Key] LIKE 'CORE_SC_TICKET_%'
- add the above setting
  setting name="Security.ShareAuthenticationTicket" value="true"/>

Answer (score 5):

Had the same exact issue here, including the same message in the log file.  In addition to deleting tickets from the Core database per Krishna's instructions, I had to delete the tickets from the Web database as well.  (There were no tickets in the Core database, but there was one in Web.)

I used the following SQL for Web database -- note that the LIKE expression is different from Krishna's:

```
DELETE FROM [YourWebDatabase].[dbo].[Properties] WHERE [Key] LIKE '%SC_TICKET%'
```

After deleting this ticket record (and without restarting IIS or deleting cookies) I re-attempted to log in at the "/sitecore" URL, and this time everything worked, with no more error page!

(I'm on Sitecore 9.2.  As far as I'm concerned this constitutes a flaw or bug in the product, as my usage of Sitecore has been fairly routine.  I believe my session timed out while I was in Experience Editor, which may be related to the appearance of the error afterward.  The username I was using was "admin".)

Answer (score 0):

Please see if the username has some special characters.

Sitecore create a ticket for each user when login onto the CMS. This ticket entry is stored in the Properties table of the Core database. So, you can check here especially.